# Скачать apk из интернета и установить

Tags: java, android, apk

Пытаюсь реализовать автообновление своего приложения на android. Долго искал, но так и не нашел рабочий способ. Итак, мне надо скачать apk файл новой версии приложения (подскажите, можно ли скачивать с ЯндексДиска) а после скачивания автоматически запустить его. Те. установить.
Программирую на java в android studio. Желательно какой-нибудь рабочий пример.
Я новичок в android dev

Мне нужно узнать, как именно скачать апк файл с сервера, поэтому я задал этот влпрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045837/android-application-self-update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: А лучше - загрузите на Google Play

Comment: А если для разработки - тогда по ADB устанавливайте

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Нет, это приложение для 5-10 человек, поэтому не мобираюсь закидывать в playMarket